# Register and accept terms button greyed out in facebook developer account

Tags: facebook, facebook-apps

Hello I am trying to register for a facebook developer account.
But looks like the accept terms button is inactive. 
Anyone knows what is the reason?
I have added the image also.
[image]

Comment: Have you tried actually _clicking_ on it perhaps …?

Comment: @CBroe offcourse Sir, I tried.

Comment: Is your account verified (by mobile or credit card)? That’s a requirement for becoming a developer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved!

I managed to register on Firefox.

I tried in Chrome incognito and it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

You can't register unless you accept the Facebook Platform Policy and Facebook Privacy Policy. Basically, as WizKid mentioned, clicking on the toggle which right now says NO. Also, flagging your questions for being unrelated to code 100%.

Answer (score 0):

Try using an incognito tab. I had the same issue on Chrome, but solved it by logging in from an incognito tab.